# Force UTF-8 while writing to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

How do I enforce UTF-8 encoding when writing a string to a file in Python?
I need it in a larger toolchain, but cannot get it running reliably.
Following different, failing, approaches from Stack Overflow, here's a MWE that already fails for me:

```
import codecs

f1 = codecs.open("/tmp/works.utf8", "w", encoding="utf-8")
f1.write("ä")
f1.close()

f2 = codecs.open("/tmp/fails.utf8", "w", encoding="utf-8")
f2.write("a")
f2.close()
```

Testing on console:

```
$ file -i works.utf8 
works.utf8: text/plain; charset=utf-8

$ file -i fails.utf8 
fails.utf8: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

What am I missing?

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. Your example is probably too short for `file` to do an informed guess, but for a longer text the `file` command will tell you the encoding is ASCII if all characters are in the ASCII range. In this case, UTF-8 and ASCII are indistinguishable (by design, that is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On python 3 you no longer use codecs to open files. There is a new `encoding` parameter on the open function:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

About the `file` program. It works by guessing the content. You would need to add a UTF-8 BOM to give it more chance of recognizing it since that could be a ascii file as well (or binary since just one byte doesn't say much about it)

Comment: … but **don’t** add a UTF-8 BOM. Nobody does that, and it drastically reduces the portability of your files.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That is a good point *most* of the time. Unless they really need files being recognized as utf-8 by some stupid program (e.g. Excel sucks reading CSV)

Comment: So the main reason for my "issue" was a misunderstanding of what file does.